# Need a selenium java technique to click browser control Block location request button in Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

edit:<So I've only managed to get one person to try to help so far, if anyone has any suggestions on how this question, post, title, tags, etc can be improved, please leave a comment. I've been searching for a fix off and on for weeks, and nothing has worked.>

I have a java selenium spring boot cucumber framework set up running tests against Firefox. I have one specific blocker where the location request box pops up and stops the interaction with parts of the site I need to test.

[image: Location Request Pop Up]

There are a LOT of answers on this site that involve disabling the location functionality in the capabilities/options, and I've tried variations on most of these, and they resemble this layout, but none have had any effect.

```
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("locationContextEnabled", false);
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("geo.enabled", false);
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("geo.prompt.testing", false);
        firefoxOptions.setCapability("geo.prompt.testing.allow", false);
```

I can't use a @Before cucumber tag to try and preload this because of the way the drivers are connected with interfaces, and the interaction with Spring Boot completely breaks the framework.

This is not an "alert", so none of the alert click through functionality will interact with this location widget.

I attempted manipulating "windowHandles()" but that seems to only work with tabs, not direct Firefox controls.

What I REALLY need is a direct way to detect that Firefox Pop Up and directly interact with the "Block" button, assuming that is possible. Since we can grab tab and url data though I have to assume that is the case until someone very knowledgeable says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

To handle the browser pop up selenium support below method for cancel or block.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
```

If you need to allow the pop up then use below code

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Comment: I specifically denoted that this is not an alert, and alert functionality does not work. This is not on the web page, it's the browser tool itself.

Comment: It looks to me a browser alert…. Can you please try this code

Comment: I did try the code, I added it in several places. I also have a wait to locate method that keeps trying navigation on the page, it dismisses notifications, closes alerts, and double checks if anything has made a menu I need to close, and it re-opens them. It is really robust after a couple of years of development. When I specifically put the close alert code in exactly the right spot to handle an alert after the page loads, my method returns my "No Alert Present" message in the terminal. It LOOKS like an alert, but it is NOT part of the page at all. It is part of the Firefox browser.

Comment: Also you can check if alert is present or not before accepting or dismissing by below

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10 /*timeout in seconds*/);
                           if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent())==null){
                                 System.out.println("alert was not present");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                            driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
                           }

Comment: And yes its part of Firefox. hence I mentioned its a browser alert

Comment: Let me try to clarify. The selenium functionality that revolves around "alerts" does not recognize it as an "alert". This is something specific to the location code of the browser binary, just like tabs, the bookmarks bar, or the favorite "star" icon. I appreciate you trying to answer, but what you are saying is all basic, well known functionality. I have all that built into my system, and it doesn't work. This is something more along the lines of windowHandles() where it needs to manipulate the actual browser controls, not something on the web page.